# Oracle SQL: Find job ID of the job for which the difference between the highest salary and the lowest is the highest one

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to solve some exercises and i am stucked with this problem, i have tried some solutions by myself but i keep getting error like "missing right parenthesis"

This is my attempt 
`select job_id
from employees
where (select max(max(salary) - min(salary) from employees as job_id)`

`select jobID
from employees
where (max(max(salary) - min(salary) as jobID)`
in this case the error is: 
`ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here`

Moreover i am not sure if this exercise should be solved with a subquery.

Comment: Yes, as the error says your brackets are not balanced. Also, WHERE clauses need a left hand side and a right hand side. Like `WHERE salary=(select max...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using the Oracle 12.1 row limiting clause (the `with` clause is just to supply dummy data without creating a table - as you already have an `employees` table you can leave it out and start at `select job_id`):

```
with employees (emp_id, job_id, salary) as
     ( select 1, 10, 11000 from dual union all
       select 2, 10, 11500 from dual union all
       select 3, 20, 12000 from dual union all
       select 4, 20, 13000 from dual union all
       select 5, 30, 45000 from dual union all
       select 6, 30, 50000 from dual
)
select job_id
     , min(salary), max(salary)
     , max(salary) - min(salary) as salary_range
from   employees
group by job_id
order by salary_range desc
fetch first row only;

    JOB_ID MIN(SALARY) MAX(SALARY) SALARY_RANGE
---------- ----------- ----------- ------------
        30       45000       50000         5000
```

Or,

```
with employees (emp_id, job_id, salary) as
     ( select 1, 10, 11000 from dual union all
       select 2, 10, 11500 from dual union all
       select 3, 20, 12000 from dual union all
       select 4, 20, 13000 from dual union all
       select 5, 30, 45000 from dual union all
       select 6, 30, 50000 from dual
     )
select job_id
from   ( select job_id
             , row_number() over (order by max(salary) - min(salary) desc) as seq
         from employees
         group by job_id )
where  seq = 1
```